# How to map to multiple elements and collect

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
final List<Toy> toys = Arrays.asList("new Toy(1)", "new Toy(2)"); 

final List<Item> itemList = toys.stream()
   .map(toy -> {
        return Item.from(toy); //Creates Item type
   }).collect(Collectors.toList);
```

This above codes work fines and will make a list of Items from the list of Toys.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
final List<Item> itemList = toys.stream()
   .map(toy -> {
        Item item1 = Item.from(toy);
        Item item2 = Item.fromOther(toy);

        List<Item> newItems = Arrays.asList(item1, item2);
        return newItems;
   }).collect(Collectors.toList);
```

OR

```
final List<Item> itemList = toys.stream()
   .map(toy -> {
        return Item item1 = Item.from(toy); 
        return Item item2 = Item.fromOther(toy); //Two returns don't make sense but just want to illustrate the idea.       
   }).collect(Collectors.toList);
```

So comparing this to the first code, the first approach returns 1 Item object for every Toy Object.

How do i make it so I can return a two Item Objects for every Toy?

--UPDATE--

```
final List<Item> itemList = toys.stream()
   .map(toy -> {
        Item item1 = Item.from(toy);
        Item item2 = Item.fromOther(toy);

        return Arrays.asList(item1,item2);
   }).collect(ArrayList<Item>::new, ArrayList::addAll,ArrayList::addAll);
```

Comment: If you have found a solution, don’t update your question with the solution.  Accept the relevant answer instead.

Comment: I haven't found the solution

Comment: @bob9123 that updated post does not say much. what is `BasicRule` and how do you map and why do you need to provide that explicitly? A minimal runnable example would help

Answer (score 14):

You are already doing that... you just need to `flatMap`

```
final List<Item> itemList = toys.stream()
.map(toy -> Arrays.asList(Item.from(toy),Item.fromOther(toy))
.flatMap(List::stream)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you drop the mapping entirely as suggested:

```
final List<Item> itemList = toys.stream()
.flatMap(toy -> Stream.of(Item.from(toy),Item.fromOther(toy))))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to return two Items for each Toy, perhaps the output type should be a `List<List<Item>>`:

```
List<List<Item>> itemList = 
    toys.stream()
        .map(toy -> Arrays.asList(Item.from(toy),Item.fromOther(toy)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList);
```

If you wish the two `Item`s per `Toy` to be collected into the same `List<Item>`, use `flatMap`:

```
List<Item> itemList = 
    toys.stream()
        .flatMap(toy -> Stream.of(Item.from(toy),Item.fromOther(toy)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList);
```

Comment: I would rather have it to be one List but contain two elements

Comment: @bob9123 In that case, you should use `flatMap` instead of `map`. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers who stumbled across the same question, there was this new fancy method added starting from Java-16 - [mapMulti](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) - it does exactly what is asked in the question and it doesn't create a new stream comparing to `flatMap`:

```
List<Item> itemList =
    toys.stream()
        .mapMulti(
            (Toy toy, Consumer<Item> consumer) -> {
              consumer.accept(Item.from(toy));
              consumer.accept(Item.fromOther(toy));
            })
        .toList();
```