# Map object to multiple objects using Java stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a question regarding Java streams. Let's say I have a stream of Object and I'd like to map each of these objects to multiple objects. For example something like

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).map(x -> (x, x*x, -x)) //...
```

Here I want to map each value to the same value, its square and the same value with opposite sign. I couldn't find any stream operation to do that. I was wondering if it would be better to map each object `x` to a custom object that has those fields, or maybe collect each value into intermediate `Map` (or any data structure).

I think that in terms of memory it could be better to create a custom object, but maybe I'm wrong.

In terms of design correctness and code clarity, which solution would be better? Or maybe there are more elegant solutions that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Try `IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(x -> new int[] {x, x*x, -x})`.

Comment: But the object is of the same type of any type?

Comment: @JoseDaSilva not in my case, but from the answers I figure there are no direct way to do it anyway

Comment: Might be [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113453/how-to-map-to-multiple-elements-and-collect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Besides using a custom class** such as:

```
class Triple{
private Integer value;
public Triple(Integer value){
 this.value = value;
}

public Integer getValue(){return this.value;}
public Integer getSquare(){return this.value*this.value;}
public Integer getOpposite(){return this.value*-1;}
public String toString() {return getValue()+", "+this.getSquare()+", "+this.getOpposite();}
}
```

and run

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
         .mapToObj(x -> new Triple(x))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

you could use apache commons InmmutableTriple to do so.
for example:

```
 IntStream.range(0, 10)
.mapToObj(x -> ImmutableTriple.of(x,x*x,x*-1))
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

maven repo: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.6

documentation: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutableTriple.html

Comment: oh wow! an entire library for `ImmutableTriple`... when there is `Arrays.asList` or `IntStream.of` or `List.of` in java=9, etc

Comment: @eugene I mentioned before that, we could use a custom class as well. anyway, I added a custom class for reference.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `flatMap` to generate an `IntStream` containing 3 elements for each of the elements of the original `IntStream`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(IntStream.range(0, 10)
                                            .flatMap(x -> IntStream.of(x, x*x, -x))
                                            .toArray()));
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 2, 4, -2, 3, 9, -3, 4, 16, -4, 5, 25, -5, 6, 36, -6, 7, 49, -7, 8, 64, -8, 9, 81, -9]
```